# Text Mining a single text document

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, rapidminer

I am new to data mining and currently working on an online news article from TOI in RapidMiner. My aim is to get results which shows the most important things mentioned in the article or to find the valuable information hidden in it.

I am done with document processing on the article "TOI manifesto" http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/specials/lok-sabha-elections-2014/news/TOI-manifesto-An-agenda-for-the-new-government/articleshow/31973967.cms.
I have applied tokenization, filtering and ngrams and got some result.

I'm stuck here. I don't know how to proceed further. Which technique/algorithm should I use in RapidMiner to get required results?

Comment: it's not clear what are the "required results". Maybe looking for words with the highest frequency?

Comment: I am looking for sentences which are giving the main information about the article. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking for data mining. Data mining is advanced statistical methods.

Often with a focus on *quantitative* analysis.

You are looking for Natural Language Processing. You don't have a large database.

You have a single document. You don't want quantitative results, but qualiative. You are using the wrong tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am using the Information extraction plugin extension in RapidMiner rite now. Will it be helpful? or else which other tool would you suggest me for this?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: I disagree with you. A single document might be considered as a data source that can be converted into a even large dataset. It is a case in which data mining might be useful to extract some patterns in the document.

Comment: The Information Extraction extension to RapidMiner has some documentation here http://www-ai.cs.uni-dortmund.de/auto?self=$fqhavm6c in case you haven't see it. Named entity recognition (NER) is mentioned a fair bit.

Comment: This site clearly states **huge document *collections***. If you work on huge documents, you only have very little time for each document, and therefore only do minimal analysis. This is why this is so different from true NLP. I think you need a specialized NLP tool, not one desinged for huge document collections. Maybe Stanford Core NLP?